# Parametric Equation part A

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, parametric

Hi everyone I am in need of some guidance solving this parametric equation question and was wondering if you guys could give me some pointers and to see if I am doing this correctly.

Here I have two functions:

$$y=1600-710t+90t^2$$
$$and$$
$$x=-100+250t-45t^2$$

my goal is to compute the values of its position, direction, velocity, and acceleration at $$t=0.8 s$$

so far from what I (hopefully) got correct is in my work below.

In calculating the position of the object moving along this path I've done the following:

inputting the value at $t=0.8s$ into the functions of $x$ and $y$

$$y=1600-710(0.8)-90(0.8)^2 $$
$$y=974.4\;{m}$$
$$x=-100+250(0.8)-45(0.8)^2$$
$$x=71.2\;{m}$$
Therefore: $$(x,y)=(71.2\;{m},974.4\;{m})$$

For Velocity, the following is:

taking the derivative of each function at $t=0.8\;{s}$ giving:

$$y'=-710+180t$$
$$v_y'=-566\;{m/s}$$
$$x'=250-90\;{m/s}$$
$$v'_x=175\;{m/s}$$

$$\vec{v}=\sqrt{{175}^2+{(-566)}^2} = 593.32\;{m/s}$$
$$\theta = Tan^{-1}{(\frac {-566}{175})} = -72.54^\circ$$

Therefore the velocity of the moving object at $t=0.8\;{s}$
is $593.32\;{m/s}$ at $\theta$ = $-72.54^\circ$

For Acceleration, taking the second-derivative:

$$a_x=-90\;{m/s^2}$$

$$a_y=180\;{m/s^2}$$

$$\vec{a}=\sqrt{{-90}^2+{180}^2}=201.2\;{m/s^2}$$
$$\theta=Tan^{-1}(\frac{180\;{m/s^2}}{-90m\;{m/s^2}}) = -63.43^\circ $$

Therefore the object is accelerating at $201.2\;{m/s^2}$  at $\theta =-63.43^\circ$

Comment: Are you doubting your understanding of velocity and acceleration, or whether you carried out the calculus correctly?  Either way, you can find similar examples done (perhaps even on YouTube) and satisfy yourself.

Comment: There is a small typo about the position. You wrote two times "45" instead of 45 and 90. 
Also you should be careful when taking the $tan^{-1}$. In case of the velocity it is correct but for the acceleration you should draw the acceleration vector and think about the "true" angle.

Comment: Oh thank you for pointing that out! I'm concerned if I carried out my calculus correctly.

Comment: @zubzub when you're speaking about true-angle do you mean where Tan(x) is negative or positive? In which case Tan(x) in my question would have to be in Quadrant 2 since it has a negative value in correlation with the acceleration components. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: @JesseRoawr Yes for the acceleration angle, the vector is in the second quadrant. First, let's simply consider $a_x$ and $a_y$ in absolute value (so consider them to be in the first quadrant) and compute the angle : $\theta = arctan(180/90) = 63.4°$. Now by drawing a small diagram, you will realize that your angle in the second quadrant is actually $180° - 63.4°$.
In general, when computing the angle with the formula $arctan(y/x)$ you should always first consider $x$ and $y$ in absolute value which will get you the angle in the first quadrant. And then think about how to "correct" the answer.

Comment: oh! I understand now, which means that 116.6° would be my true angle relative to the initial side. 

This would also be the case for velocity correct?

In which given my work is correct the object would be moving up(?)